# Factorization Patterns for Ideals

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a Galois Number field.  Let $p$ be an unramified rational prime.  In this extension, for any $P,Q | p\mathcal{O}_K$ then the relative degrees $f(P) := [\mathcal{O}_K/P : \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}]$ satisfy $f(P) = f(Q)$.  The Chebotarev density theorem gives statistical information on the size of sets of rational primes $p$ such that the primes lying above $p$ have a specific Frobenius conjugacy class.  On the other hand, it does not provide information on how many rational primes in Galois extensions have a fixed $f(P)$ (aside from primes that split i.e. $f(P) = 1$, which will have trivial conjugacy class).
Are there any general results about the statistics of primes with specific values $f(P)$? In the Abelian case? I would appreciate any references about this.

Comment: The Frobenius conjugacy class determines $f(P)$ -- it's just the order in the group of any element of the conjugacy class -- so you can read this off immediately from Chebotarev.

Comment: @David Loeffler: This is certainly true. But how many conjugacy classes will occur with that value of $f(P)$? How large must they be?

Comment: That is simply a question about the number of elements of each order in the Galois group: the density of rational primes for which $f(P) = r$ for some (and hence all) $P \mid p$ is exactly $ \{$# of elts of G of order r $\}/$#G.

Comment: Note $f(P)=f(Q)$ isn't guaranteed to be true unless $p$ is unramified. Indeed Chebotarev density can be leveraged to predict the density of *any* kind of splitting type of a prime, even in finite *non*-Galois extensions. I explain how that works in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711084/how-to-determine-the-density-of-the-set-of-completely-splitting-primes-for-a-fin/711211#711211).

Comment: @sea turtles. Edited, thank you for catching that